# Javascript evaluations

Tags: javascript, evaluation

I'm a having some trouble trying to fully understand how some javascript evaluations work.

Can anybody help me in finding out what does this javascript line??

```
n >= 4 && t === 400 || n >= 5 && t === 500 || (n < 6 && n++, i(n))
```

Comment: Which bit don't you understand? I could make 8 different questions out of this off the top of my head.

Comment: A quick search for each operator should let you work this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It groups the logical `OR` parts as else parts

```
if (n >= 4 && t === 400) {
} else if(n >= 5 && t === 500) {
} else {
    if (n < 6) {
        n++;
    }
    i(n);
}
```

Comment: That was my thought, but it seemed weird to me to execute two comparisons as exit conditions... instead of something like... 

if !(n>=4 && t===400) && !(n >=5 && t===500) && (n<6){
 n++;
 i(n);
    }